# How to boot to windows 10 after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, windows

I have dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and since then I can't boot to windows any more. It gives me choices but windows isn't one of them.

How can I boot again to Windows?

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? Did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows as grub can only boot another system if installed in same boot mode. And did you turn off Windows fast start up hibernation as grub cannot boot hibernated Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see windows in the grub menu open ubuntu and open a console in that console type `sudo update-grub` And that should fix the problem!

Comment: i used ubuntu boot repair it fixed my problem